# Having error in creating react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

From the past 2 hours, I am trying to get into creating a new app but I am constantly facing this:

```
Ninjas-Mac:react-projects nabeel$ create-react-native-app application
Uncaught Error { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/nabeel/.expo/state.json.1311545250']
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Users/nabeel/.expo/state.json.1311545250' }
Ninjas-Mac:react-projects nabeel$
```

Comment: which os are you using ..?

Comment: I am using macOS Mojave

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and fixed it with below command

```
sudo chmod 777 /Users/nabeel/.expo/state.json
```

or open new terminal hit below commnd

```
ls -al
```

check that file
if you got then hit

```
sudo chmod 777 state.json
```

its working fine here.

Comment: I am not getting such file :(

Comment: see in your error its permission error so you should have  /Users/nabeel/.expo/state.json  file in this location.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

$ brew install node

$ brew install watchman

$ npm install -g react-native-cli

$ react-native init MyNewProject

$ cd MyNewProject

$ react-native run-ios